# How to resolve a controller with make parameter in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Previously I could do something like this:

***/var/www/laravel/app/Http/Controllers/HelloController.php***

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Hello\Hello as Hello;

class HelloController extends Controller {
    public function index() {

        $o = new Hello;

        $o = new Hello('changed1','changed1');

        var_dump($o);
    }
}
```

***/var/www/laravel/app/Models/Hello***

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Hello;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model\Hello.php;


class Hello extends Model
{
    public function __construct($one='default1', $two='default2')
    {
        echo "First  Param: $one","\n<br>\n";
        echo "Second Param: $two","\n<br>\n";
        echo "\n<br>\n";
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('tutorial', function() {
    $app = app(); 
    $app->make('Hello');
});
```

Instantiating without make works, but this now brings an error:

`ReflectionException in Container.php line 776: Class Hello does not exist`

What do you think I am missing in here?

Comment: Apparently you're missing 'hello'

Comment: :) where I should apply this?

Comment: did you try `composer dump`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your class has a `namespace` of `App\Models\Hello`, you must use the `namespace` of it when trying to instantiate the class. Therefore, your code should be like this:

```
Route::get('tutorial', function() {
    $app = app(); 
    $app->make('App\Models\Hello\Hello');
});
```

To expand a bit in the answer, you can remove the `make()` method call and just use the `app()` helper, and you'll end up with the same result:

```
Route::get('tutorial', function() {
    $app = app(); 
    $app->make('App\Models\Hello\Hello');

    // you can achieve the same with the
    // `app()` helper using less characters :)
    app('App\Models\Hello\Hello');
});
```

Comment: @funguy Since your file structure is **app/Models/Hello.php** a more correct namespace for the model would be `App\Models`. Which would result in `$app->make('App\Models\Hello');`. Well, spotted though